# md-checkbox Angular materials styling

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material2

Using Angular materials with Angular4, I cannot find a way to change checkbox color after checked.

The only way worked for me to modify styling at the initial view is:

```
:host /deep/ .mat-checkbox-inner-container{
     height:15px;
     width:15px; 
     background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.87);
}
```

Trying to change styling after on checked, the following did not worked:

```
:host /deep/ .mat-checkbox-checked {
background-color:yellow;   
}
```

It actually applied after check, but in wrong element - did not apply at the inner container.

Something like `:host /deep/ .mat-checkbox-inner-container-checked` does not work as well.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I faced the Same issue

Comment: Here is one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620563/showing-material-checkbox-animation-on-hover/62002529#62002529

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this one :)

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: rgb(27, 142, 241) !important;
}

.mat-ripple-element {
  background: rgba(27, 142, 241, .4) !important;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had to add `::ng-deep` before both starting lines. I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: `::ng-deep` is required as @SamersSalib mentioned

Answer (score 5):

Try this one :)

```css
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
       .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background
{
  background-color: rgb(27, 142, 241) !important;
}

/deep/ .mat-ripple-element {
  background: rgba(27, 142, 241, .4) !important;
}
```

Here the `/deep/` is important otherwise it will not work. According to Angular documentation:

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's own template.
>
> Use the `/deep/` shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ combinator works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the view children and content children of the component.
>
> The `/deep/` combinator also has the aliases `>>>`, and `::ng-deep`.
>
> — https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.md-checkbox.md-checked` Refer [Checkbox Styling](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/checkbox),

```
:host /deep/ .md-checkbox.md-checked .md-icon {
   background-color:yellow!important;   
}
```

Comment: didn't worked for me. Still keeps the default(pink) color.

Comment: Try to use `.md-checkbox.md-checked` with `!important`.

Comment: @RohanKumar, the link you shared is for the AngularJS Materials... The OP specifies Angular 4.  [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#theming) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component.ts file

and in css:

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background: yellow;
}
```