# Showing Material Checkbox Animation On Hover

Tags: css, checkbox, sass, angular-material

Check out the effect at this [link](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/checkbox) where the circular background of the checkbox is shown on hover. How can I get this same behavior while using `<mat-checkbox>` in Angular? I want the background to show on hover as well as the normal animation on transitions from checked to unchecked, unchecked to checked, etc. I am using `@angular/material` version 6.4.5. By inspecting the documentation for version 7.1.1, a `persistent-ripple` class is applied to a `<div>` inside the checkbox on hover. This does not happen in the documentation for version 6.4.7. The link for the older documentation is [here](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api).

Comment: Angular material checkbox is already implemented like so. Did you check the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) and the examples provided?

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that I am on `@angular/material` version 6.4.5, and looking at the docs for version 6.4.7, it does not seem like this behavior is default on checkboxes.

Comment: You're right, tested it with version 6.4.7 and it is not the default behaviour. I suggest you either to update to latest version (if this is feasible for your project), or, as you've done, check the differences between versions and try to implement it on your own.

Comment: Taking a look at the docs, this is the class that applies on hover: `.mat-checkbox-inner-container:hover .mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple {
    opacity: .04;
}` you would have to use `::ng-deep` to target `.mat-checkbox-inner-container:hover`

Answer (score 2):

In css file, I have added the following code,

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-inner-container:hover .mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple { opacity: .04; background: red($color: #000000);}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-inner-container:hover{ opacity: 1; background: red($color: #000000);}
```